# How to open a url from html to open instagram app by default

Tags: html

I need to open my html page url to directly open instagram app without asking me to select the app. I tried like this
`<a  target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/{userid}?r=nametag" >`
but here when i click on the link its asking me to select instagram app from 2 options.
I need to directly open instagram.

Answer (score 1):

This should open it directly:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/{username}"/>

<a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead.

`<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>`

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL from an HTML page and directly open the Instagram app without asking to select from multiple options, you can use the following format:

```html
<a href="instagram://user?username={username}">Open Instagram</a>
```

Replace `{username}` with the Instagram username you want to open. However, note that this method may not work on all devices or browsers since it depends on the device's configuration and whether the Instagram app is installed.